# Docker doesn't allow to view /proc/xxx/stack?

Tags: linux, docker, stack, cat, proc

I'm using docker linux image, and "cat /proc/xxx/status" always OK, but "cat /proc/xxx/stack" always files:

```
[root@1680d0b1bdde test]# cat /proc/17/stack
cat: /proc/17/stack: Operation not permitted
```

Why is this? Is this a docker limitation or config issue? I'm using default centos image with root username.

Thanks.

---

I get this answer now, on starting the docker image, I must specify "--privileged" command line option to make sure it runs as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a kernel limitation/protection.